# Is there a way to have my checkboxes alinged horizontally with a fixed number using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, razor, bootstrap-4

I don't want my checkboxes under each other but alinged next to each other. But only in columns of 5 for example.

At the moment I have something like this:

[Checkboxes vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLe5T.png)

But i want this:

```
[x] label [x] label [x] label [x] label [x] label
[x] label [x] label [x] label [x] label [x] label
```

This is my code:

```
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col col-md-3">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsKlassen">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              Klassen <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
            </h5>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-9 collapse" id="collapsKlassen"style="margin-right: 5px;">
          <div class="form-check  "  >
            <div >
              @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CheckBoxKlassen)
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Already tried with formcheck inline etc, but not giving result.
 EDIT:
Rendered code:

```
<input id="CheckBoxKlassen_0__ID" name="CheckBoxKlassen[0].ID" type="hidden" value="61" />
<input id="CheckBoxKlassen_0__Display" name="CheckBoxKlassen[0].Display" type="hidden" value="BIO 1Aa" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The WasChecked field is required." id="CheckBoxKlassen_0__WasChecked" name="CheckBoxKlassen[0].WasChecked" type="hidden" value="False" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsChecked field is required." id="CheckBoxKlassen_0__IsChecked" name="CheckBoxKlassen[0].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<label for="CheckBoxKlassen_0__IsChecked">BIO 1Aa</label>
<br /><input id="CheckBoxKlassen_1__ID" name="CheckBoxKlassen[1].ID" type="hidden" value="64" />
<input id="CheckBoxKlassen_1__Display" name="CheckBoxKlassen[1].Display" type="hidden" value="BIO 1Ab" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The WasChecked field is required." id="CheckBoxKlassen_1__WasChecked" name="CheckBoxKlassen[1].WasChecked" type="hidden" value="False" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsChecked field is required." id="CheckBoxKlassen_1__IsChecked" name="CheckBoxKlassen[1].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<label for="CheckBoxKlassen_1__IsChecked">BIO 1Ab</label>
<br /><input id="CheckBoxKlassen_2__ID" name="CheckBoxKlassen[2].ID" type="hidden" value="58" />
<input id="CheckBoxKlassen_2__Display" name="CheckBoxKlassen[2].Display" type="hidden" value="BIO 1Ac" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The WasChecked field is required." id="CheckBoxKlassen_2__WasChecked" name="CheckBoxKlassen[2].WasChecked" type="hidden" value="False" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsChecked field is required." id="CheckBoxKlassen_2__IsChecked" name="CheckBoxKlassen[2].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<label for="CheckBoxKlassen_2__IsChecked">BIO 1Ac</label>
<br /><input id="CheckBoxKlassen_3__ID" name="CheckBoxKlassen[3].ID" type="hidden" value="71" />
<input id="CheckBoxKlassen_3__Display" name="CheckBoxKlassen[3].Display" type="hidden" value="BIO 1Ad" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The WasChecked field is required." id="CheckBoxKlassen_3__WasChecked" name="CheckBoxKlassen[3].WasChecked" type="hidden" value="False" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsChecked field is required." id="CheckBoxKlassen_3__IsChecked" name="CheckBoxKlassen[3].IsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<label for="CheckBoxKlassen_3__IsChecked">BIO 1Ad</label>
<br /><input id="CheckBoxKlassen_4__ID" name="CheckBoxKlassen[4].ID" type="hidden" value="59" />
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. As of now we can't see how the rendered html look like.

Comment: I edited the post with a screenshot

Comment: Nobody can debug an image, for that the actual code is needed, as text.

Comment: The actual code is at the bottom of my post? What do you need more? Then i can provide it. CheckBoxKlassen is a list with checkboxes

Comment: The code we see is the razor code that generates the `input/label`'s, and what you ask is how to style the latter, and as we can't see how they are rendered, markup-wise, we won't be able to suggest anything meaningful.

Comment: Added part of the rendered html

Comment: you will need to use loop counters and insert appropriate containers ie. rows

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example , you could refer to and make the modification according to your need.

**Model**

```
 public class CheckBoxKlassen
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBoxViewModel
{
    public IList<CheckBoxKlassen> CheckBoxKlassen { get; set; }
}
```

**CheckBoxList.cshtml** , use the **CSS** to align checkboxes horizontally and change the width percent of `<li>` to adjust the number of checkboxes per line.

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.CheckBoxViewModel
<style>
  .checkbox-grid li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
   }
</style>

<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col col-md-3">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsKlassen">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
            Klassen <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
        </h5>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-9 collapse" id="collapsKlassen" style="margin-right: 5px;">
    <div class="form-check  ">
        <ul class="checkbox-grid">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxKlassen.Count(); i++)
            {
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="CheckBoxKlassen[i].IsChecked" value="@Model.CheckBoxKlassen[i].Id" />
                <label >@Model.CheckBoxKlassen[i].Display</label>
            </li>

            }
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller** , get the data of checkboxlist

```
public IActionResult CheckBoxList()
    {
        CheckBoxViewModel model = new CheckBoxViewModel()
        {
            CheckBoxKlassen = _context.CheckBoxKlassen.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefer using flexbox for cases like this. You can check [a super easy, fast explaining guide here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This in combination with the [CSS calc function](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I find one of the best ways to do styling.

This CSS code should work:

```
div.form-check { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 100%; }

div.form-check div { flex-basis: 20%; }
```

Comment: No, that code won't work, and there is no way of telling what _will_ work, as we can't see the actual code they ask about.